Identify Outliers in a Single Group or Combination of Groups
I have a dataset containing cost information for products, which is grouped by the manufacturer ID, reseller ID, and product ID.
Sample Data:
        Manufacturer Reseller Product_ID Avg_Cost
 1:         M001     R001       P001       10
 2:         M001     R002       P001       15
 3:         M001     R002       P002      100
 4:         M002     R001       P003       40
 5:         M002     R003       P003       50
 6:         M002     R004       P004        3
 7:         M003     R001       P001       12
 8:         M004     R002       P001      520
 9:         M004     R005       P002      125
10:         M005     R002       P002      300
11:         M005     R006       P004        8
12:         M005     R007       P005       30
13:         M005     R008       P005       30

My goal is find and classify outlier instances on the avg_cost for each product (This will likely be iterated on but starting with something simple like 3*IQR is fine, if that needs to be specified). I would like to know if the outlier is attributed to the manufacturer, the reseller, or the combination of the two. I have tried using the identify_outliers function from the rstatix library as it allows for grouping -- but I can't see a path to the desired output I am looking for which would be something like:
    Manufacturer Reseller Product_ID Avg_Cost m_outlier r_outlier mr_outlier
 1:         M001     R001       P001       10         0         0          0
 2:         M001     R002       P001       15         0         0          0
 3:         M001     R002       P002      100         0         0          0
 4:         M002     R001       P003       40         1         0          0
 5:         M002     R003       P003       50         0         1          0
 6:         M002     R004       P004        3         0         0          0
 7:         M003     R001       P001       12         0         0          0
 8:         M004     R002       P001      520         0         1          1
 9:         M004     R005       P002      125         0         0          0
10:         M005     R002       P002      300         1         0          0
11:         M005     R006       P004        8         0         1          0
12:         M005     R007       P005       30         0         0          0
13:         M005     R008       P005       30         0         0          0

In the dataset, there are approximately 100 Manufacturers, 50000 Resellers, and 1000 products in the dataset, with the average Manufacturer having ~400 Resellers.
If I need to do this piecewise and concatenate the Manufacturer ID + Reseller ID for that part, then that should be fine. However, any guidance on best practice for a situation like this would be greatly appreciated. And if there is any other information I can provide to make this question better, please just let me know!
EDIT: identify_outliers does not seem able to get the desired output. Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Sample Issue of identify_outliers flagging all values in group as outliers:
# A tidytable: 23 x 2
   product     cost
       <chr>      <dbl>
     1 a            1  
     2 a            1.1
     3 a            1.2
     4 a            1.3
     5 a            1.4
     6 a            1.5
     7 a            1  
     8 a            2  
     9 a            1  
    10 a            1.6
    11 a            1.7
    12 a            1.8
    13 a            2  
    14 b         2422  
    15 b         2526  
    16 b         2600  
    17 b         2590  
    18 b       123424  
    19 c            4  
    20 c            3  
    21 c            1  
    22 c            2  
    23 c            1  


  tmp %>%
      group_by(product) %>%
      identify_outliers(cost)

# A tidytable: 5 x 4
  product   cost is.outlier is.extreme
  <chr>    <dbl> <lgl>      <lgl>     
1 b         2422 TRUE       TRUE      
2 b         2526 TRUE       TRUE      
3 b         2600 TRUE       TRUE      
4 b         2590 TRUE       TRUE      
5 b       123424 TRUE       TRUE 


I assume that outliers are only meaningful within a product. I think you can get what you want by grouping by product and using identify_outliers. Rename the new columns Prod_outlier & Prod_extreme. Group the new data frame by Product and Manf. and use identify_outliers again. Rename the new columns Resell_outlier & Resell_extreme. Group the new data frame by Product & Reseller and use identify_outliers again. Name the new columns Manf_outlier & Manuf_extreme. Your results may depend a lot on the definition of "outlier" and the number of Manf. and Resellers for a product.

@FJCC -- Thank you for the input. Is this roughly what you're saying? The change in row counts seems concerning so I might be off track.
df %>% ## 3.2M rows   group_by(prod_cd) %>%    identify_outliers(avg_cost) -> odf1 ## 91,142 rows names(odf1)[5:6] <- c('prod_outlier', 'prod_extreme')
odf1 %>%    group_by(prod_cd, mf_id) %>%   identify_outliers(avg_cost) -> odf2 ## 5,898 rows names(odf2)[7:8] <- c('rs_outlier', 'rs_extreme')
odf2 %>%    group_by(prod_cd, seller_id) %>%   identify_outliers(avg_cost) -> odf3 ## 16 rows 

The documentation of the function's return value says 'Returns the input data frame with two additional columns: "is.outlier"and "is.extreme"', so I would not expect the number of rows to change. If it returns only the rows where is.outlier it TRUE, you will have to save the returned data frame and left join it to the original data. If you post some data large enough to be realistic, I could do some tests. Can you mock up a small data set named DF and post the output of dput(DF) in your question?.

outlier can be valued based or dimension based.       We can use box-plot method, or 3sigma method and etc, because the data value is key.  just find the lower bound, upper bound. For the points which out out the bound ,  they are  outliers or extreme value based on the criterial.                        For dimension based on outlier detection,  more than one feature(column) are in the detection,  My favorite method is isolated forest outlier detect, or PCA method.          In your case,  we need defined the outlier first. if it is not only avg_price,  then machine learing based outlier help.

@FJCC -- The joins back to the original df worked. But, when doing some QA checks I noticed that if the average cost of a product is higher than most other products, it's labeling every row for that product as an outlier -- when the expected behavior would be to look for outliers within each product group (where there should be few labeled outliers per product) and then across manf/seller. Any idea here? Thanks!

@James Snay - Without seeing your code and some data, I can't guess what the cause is. I tried a little test and if I grouped the data, members of a high cost group were not flagged. But that doesn't mean a different configuration wouldn't lead to what you are seeing. Try to make a small data set that reproduces the problem and post it in your question.

@FJCC -- Please see question. I added an example which shows the issue I encountered at the larger scale.

I'm putting this response to the edits of the question in an answer because a reprex isn't appropriate for a comment. I do not get the result shown in the question with all of product b selected as an outlier.
My versions of dplyr and rstatix are:
rstatix_0.7.2    dplyr_1.1.4 
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(rstatix)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'rstatix'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
tmp <- structure(list(product = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
                                  "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", 
                                  "c", "c", "c"), 
                      cost = c(1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1, 2, 1, 
                               1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 2, 2422, 2526, 2600, 2590, 123424, 4, 3, 1, 2, 
                               1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -23L))
tmp %>%
  group_by(product) %>%
  identify_outliers(cost)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 4
#>   product   cost is.outlier is.extreme
#>   <chr>    <dbl> <lgl>      <lgl>     
#> 1 b       123424 TRUE       TRUE

Created on 2024-11-25 with reprex v2.1.1

I was able to recreate this output when only loading dplyr/rstatix. So perhaps there is a dependency masked by Tidyverse that is causing some issue. I will re-run for the actual data and compare results. Thanks for confirming this!
